# this function do not worked

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

do not work

```
 Create Function MyFunction(@enterpriseId uniqueidentifier)

RETURNS TABLE
AS
if @enterpriseId = 1
begin
//Do someThing
end
else
begin
//Do somethin
end
```

Comment: Have you already tried? Is there any particular problem you're facing?

Comment: Well you never add to `x` so it's just an empty list. I will optimize this for you: `SELECT TOP 0 * FROM X`.

Comment: Table valued functions are quite limited. Consider a stored procedure. If it's not suitable, you can try something like `SELECT ... FROM [X] WHERE ( @EnterpriseId = 1 AND Condition1... ) OR ( @EnterpriseId <> 1 AND Condition2... )`

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple sql query or a procedure?

```
Select * from documentItem
    where CreateDate <= @creatDate
```

You change your question???